# Fullcalendar not showing axis times for 15 min slots

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I set my fullcalendar to have 15 minute slots, however it is not showing the minute breakouts.

For example, it will show 9am, 10am, 11am, etc. but not 9am, 9:15am, 9:30am, etc.

It shows the minute breakouts for other slots like 10 minutes, but I can't get it to work for 15.

I've looked around and saw this post: [How to show all text on the axis for each minute slots rather than just 6am, 7am etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921945/how-to-show-all-text-on-the-axis-for-each-minute-slots-rather-than-just-6am-7am)

but I can't find the function that user is referring to in his proposed resolution.  Perhaps the script was updated since then.

Does anyone know how I can get the minute breakouts to show?

Comment: Can you post your initialization code?

Comment: @BGM thanks for the comment, I should've posted that.  I was simply using the sample initialization without edits so forgot to enter it.  I figured it out though as shown below.

Answer (score 8):

I know it has been a long time but for anyone who has the same problem you can try using:

```
slotDuration: '00:15:00',
slotLabelInterval: 15,
slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
```

in fullcalendar v2

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your calendar like the example below.
Please see my jsfiddle example for your solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/ahmetyildirim/pk7na5jL/

It works with Fullcalendar v3.2.0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaWeek,month,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    businessHours: {
      // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
      dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Friday

      start: '08:00', // a start time (8am in this example)
      end: '18:00' // an end time (6pm in this example)
    },
    minTime: '06:30:00',
    maxTime: '19:30:00',
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotLabelInterval: 15,
    slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
    defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
    slotMinutes: 15,

    events: [{
      title: 'test',
      start: '2016-01-11T09:30:00',
      end: '2016-01-11T12:30:00'
    }]
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. While using the fullcalendar.min.js if you comment out:

```
u=h.getMinutes();
```

it will show the minutes properly on the Y axis.  I couldn't find where it was since the other post I linked above wasn't using the "min" version of the script file.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the line stated by @Cineno. Instead I edited this line:

```
th class='fc-agenda-axis "+u+"'>"+(!ya||!ja?D(w,y("axisFormat")):"& nbsp;"+D(w,y("axisFormat")))+"/th>
```

by adding `+D(w,y("axisFormat"))) after & nbsp;`

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, i need to change

```
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat')) : '&nbsp;') +
```

to

```
((!minutes) ? formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat')) : "<small>" + formatDate(d, ':mm') + "</small>") +
```

I'll say the best way is to add an option ex. "axisSlotFormat"

Answer (score 0):

are you implementing agendaWeek, agendaDay?

```
header: {
left: 'title',
center: '',
right: 'prev,today,next,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
```

Thanks