# PrimeFaces Schedule not showing all times with some SlotDuration configuration

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar, schedule

When using the default slotDuration of PrimeFaces Schedule, or "00:15:00" for an example, the component don't show all times. If I change it to some values like "00:45:00" or even "00:15:01", the schedule show all times correctly.

Inspecting the HTML/CSS, in the cases of not showing the time, the `<td>` tag don't have a `<span>` tag inside with the time, and has the CSS class "fc-minor"

I couldn't find in documentation about this problem. I already tested with the deprecated slotMinutes, but it has the same behaviour.

Schedule with blank spaces between times:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL55A.jpg

Schedule code:

```
<p:schedule id="agendaOcupacional" allDaySlot="false" timeFormat="HH:mm" axisFormat="HH:mm" 
        draggable="false" resizable="false" slotDuration="00:15:00"  timeZone="GMT-3" 
    displayEventEnd="true"  value="#{agendamentoBean.lazyEventModel}" locale="br"/>
```

I'm using Primefaces 6.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you work on a [mcvo] usable to easily reproduce this?

Comment: Hi Selaron, sorry but I don't understand what mcvo means.

Comment: he meant [mcve] which is written as [ mcve ] and not [ mcvo ]

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje. I pasted the code in the question now. Even if you try using just <p:schedule/> with mapped value, you guys will get blank times.

Comment: oups, sorry ...

Comment: Tried removing the locale? The timezone? The draggable etc?

Comment: Yes. As I already said in the comment above, even if you use schedule in the basic way won't show all the times. Will show something like 6am - blank - 7am - blank - 8am, not the correctly 6am - 6:30am - 7am and etc

Comment: Primefaces 7.0 has major updates to the Schedule component including updating its underlying JS library FullCalendarJS.  Its possible it was already fixed. See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+schedule+is%3Aclosed+milestone%3A7.0+

Comment: @Melloware tested and still have blank spaces.

Comment: I posted an imgur image for any doubt.

Comment: it shows 6am-blank-6:30am-blank etc since you have a slot duration of 15 minutes. The slots in between are the 6:15, 6:45 etc... So effectively try to see if this is a FullCalendarJS issue on how to show the time for each slot. This is not something PrimeFaces renders

Comment: Is this the issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142682/fullcalendar-not-showing-axis-times-for-15-min-slots

Comment: I found in FullCalendarJS the attrib "slotLabelInterval", now I will try to change his value. Thanks @Kukeltje.

Comment: @Melloware yes. Primefaces has a slotLabelFormat but don't have the slotLabelInterval for setting this. I will try with JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears PF is missing the value for slotLabelInterval which fixes this issue.

I created this GitHub issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4896

Submitted this PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/4897

Hopefully it will be fixed in PrimeFaces 7.1.

For now you can use the Extender to configure it: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/schedule?id=extender-method

Comment: And it can't currently be done in an 'extender' way?

Comment: Oh it absolutely can be done with the Extender. Edited my answer.

Comment: I have used the 'extender' way and it works. Thank you both.